# On My iPhone / On My iPad folders, how to create a folder for my app?

Tags: ios, swift

Can someone show me how to create a folder for my app within the "On My iPhone" location that is visible via Files App?

I notice other apps have folders create there with their icons, but I can find ZERO developer documentation that talks about the "On My iPhone" or "On My iPad" folders.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To get your files can appear in the Files app, you must first specify that your app supports "Open in Place" and "File Sharing Enabled".

These options are configured using keys in your Info.plist file. The first key is `UIFileSharingEnabled`, which enables iTunes sharing of files in your Documents folder.

The second key is `LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace`, which grants the local file provider access to files in your Documents folder.

Add these two keys to your Info.plist and set their values to YES.

[image: Add These Keys to your Info.plist]

Everything I'm saying here I found in [this BigNerd tutorial](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/working-with-the-files-app-in-ios-11/).